# Scatterplot in seaborn 0.8

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm on a remote server where I have access to `seaborn=0.8.1` and have no way of updating the package. I'd like to use `seaborn.scatterplot`, but I'm getting an error that the function does not exist. 
Either the function did not exist in the older version, or it had a different name. I am unable to find earlier versions of the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html) (numpy does a great job of providing manuals for earlier versions), so I am kind of stuck here.

How do I find out the API for earlier versions of seaborn, and whether there are older alternatives to scatterplot?

Comment: There are no older alternatives to `scatterplot`. But you can easily use `plt.scatter` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the GitHub repo to find documentation of older versions - just navigate to the correct tag that corresponds to your version, and enter the doc directory -

https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/tree/v0.8.1/doc

It's very common for documentation to be stored alongside the code and versioned along with it.

It seems the `scatterplot` function was added in 0.9 to `seaborn/relational.py`, which has the line:
`__all__ = ["relplot", "scatterplot", "lineplot"]`, so "seaborn.scatterplot" gets "created" when `seaborn/__init__.py` performs `from .relational import *`.

I'm not sure if there's a similar function in v0.8.1. A quick search shows that class `class _RegressionPlotter(_LinearPlotter)` has a method called `scatterplot` in version 0.8.1, but I don't think it's the same (not familiar enough with Seaborn to know).

Comment: Maybe also mention the web archive, like http://web.archive.org/web/20171125070526/http://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html